# How to avoid storing mail account and database password in plain text in codeigniter 3

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have created a codeigniter 3 helper to send mails from different modules of application. I am using my gmail account to send all the mails and it works perfectly fine except that i have to store my gmail password inside the helper php file.

```
$config = Array(
    'protocol' => 'smtp',
    'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
    'smtp_port' => 465,
    'smtp_user' => 'saurabh@gmail.com',
    'smtp_pass' => 'my password',
    'mailtype'  => 'html', 
    'charset'   => 'iso-8859-1'
);
$this->load->library('email', $config);
$this->email->set_newline("\r\n");

$result = $this->email->send();
```

How can i avoid storing the plain text password in the above code while still able to use my gmail account. Same is true for my database password, I am storing plaintext database password in the codeigniter's database.php configuration file. How this can be avoided ?

Comment: can't we store these settings in database? In database save the password as encrypted.

Comment: Still I have to at least store my database password in plain text. Which i don't want.

Comment: save your password as encrypted.

Comment: @Drudge can you help by giving some directions on how to store passwords in encrypted format.

Comment: check this linkn buddy . http://codeinphp.github.io/post/development-environments-in-codeigniter/

Answer (score 1):

Database password cannot be hidden or connvert it in other way. But how ever no one can access your config files with the browser.

And in email password can be done. You can keep it in database and on mail sending place you can call it.

> FYI -   your project files cant access with browser or any other. Thats the reason we use frameworks. Bcz its security level is higher than normal oop pograms.
>
> So your password and other stuff will not be public at any how.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I see it possible is to use `Gmails OAUTH` mechanism instead of smtp method. here's the link to the api `https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2` and some examples `https://developers.google.com/gmail/xoauth2_libraries#php_sample`. Rest assured you will have to put your plain password somewhere in your app (either in DB or at a location in file system which no one has access to except apache) or write a crypt function (even this function requires/ outputs the plain password)